# Understanding the proof of functoriality in Kleisli Category

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading Borceux volume 2 on Category Theory. In Proposition 4.1.6 the author wants to show that full subcategory of $\mathcal C^T$ generated by the free $T$-algebras is equivalent to the Kleisli category (i.e. $\mathcal C_t$).

In order to prove it this, one of the steps involves defining a functor $\phi:\mathcal C_T \to CˆT$ where $\phi(C) = (TC, \mu_C)$ and $\phi(f)= \mu_D \circ T f$ where $f:C \to TD$, i.e. $f:C \to D$ in $\mathcal C_T$.

Now, the author wants to prove that $\phi$ is indeed a functor, and here writes the following in order to prove the composition property, i.e. that $\phi(f \circ g) = \phi(f) \ circ \phi(g)$.

He gives the following proof, which is the one I'm trying to further distill.

$$
\phi(g) \circ \phi(f) = \mu_C \circ T(g) \circ \mu_B \circ T(f) = \mu_C \circ \mu_{T(C)} \circ TT(g) \circ T(f) =
$$
$$
\mu_C \circ T(\mu_C)\circ TT(g) \circ T(f) = \mu_c \circ T(\mu_C \circ T(g) \circ f) = \phi(g \circ f).
$$

So I'm trying to understand how each equality is obtained, and for this, I'm walking backwards. Hence, we start from:

$$
\phi(g \circ f) = 
\mu_c \circ T(\mu_C \circ T(g) \circ f) = 
\mu_C \circ T(\mu_C)\circ TT(g) \circ T(f)
$$

The first equality is just the definition of $\phi$ and the second is just the functoriality property of $T$.

The next step is
$$
\mu_C \circ T(\mu_C)\circ TT(g) \circ T(f) = 
\mu_C \circ \mu_{T(C)} \circ TT(g) \circ T(f)
$$

My guess is that the associativity of the monad $T$ gives us that
$$
\mu_C \circ T(\mu_C) = \mu_C \circ \mu_C T = \mu_C \circ \mu_{T(C)}
$$

Thus, we are left with the last equality, which I'm stuck...

Any help? Are the steps so far correct?

Just to be clear, the question is on the equality:
$$
\mu_C \circ T(g) \circ \mu_B \circ T(f) = \mu_C \circ \mu_{T(C)} \circ TT(g) \circ T(f)
$$
I don't understand why this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the problem. The penultimate step: $$\mu_C\circ T(\mu_C)\circ TT(g)\circ T(f)=\mu_C\circ T(\mu_C\circ T(g)\circ f)$$Follows from: $$T(\mu_C)\circ TT(g)\circ T(f)=T(\mu_C\circ T(g))\circ T(f)=T(\mu_C\circ T(g)\circ f)$$For $T$ is a functor.

The very last step follows from the definition of $\phi$ and the definition of composition in the Kleisli category; $g\circ f=\mu_C\circ T(g)\circ f$. Then: $$\mu_C\circ T(\underset{\text{composition in $C$}}{\underbrace{\mu_C\circ T(g)\circ f}})=\mu_C\circ T(\underset{\text{composition in $C^T$}}{\underbrace{g\circ f}})=\phi(g\circ f)$$Which is the correct thing; in writing $\phi(g\circ f)=\phi(g)\circ\phi(f)$, we want the RHS to feature composition in $C$ and the LHS to feature composition in $C^T$.

In the edited question, the equality: $$\mu_C\circ \underbrace{T(g)\circ\mu_B}\circ T(f)=\mu_C\circ\underbrace{\mu_{T(C)}\circ TT(g)}\circ T(f)$$Follows from the fact that the underbraced expressions are equal. Why are they equal? Simply by the axiomatic assumption that $\mu$ is a natural transformation $TT\implies T$ (remember $g:B\to TC$).

Comment: I didn't follow your point. I'm having trouble understanding how $\mu_C \circ T(g) \circ \mu_B \circ T(f) = \mu_C \circ \mu_{T(C)} \circ TT(g) \circ T(f)$

Comment: @DaviBarreira in fairness, that was one of the first steps not the last step. I will add something about that one as well

Comment: Sorry if the question became convoluted. I wrote that I was walking "backwards", this was supposed to mean that the order was reversed. My apologies.

Comment: @DaviBarreira no worries, the other equality you're concerned about I've addressed. It's really just naturality of $\mu$